# how do i make .jar become executable in Xubuntu

Tags: java, terminal, xubuntu

I am Trying To Write a .sh file to ask file name, make file executable, then open file. I have tried to search but did not find a result to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Though the first sentence of question is ambiguous but what i conceived you want to run a .jar file. Simply java -jar yourfile.jar

Comment: i want the program to ask file  name

Comment: the make executable, then open with OpenJDK 7